# Saving page ID within $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I am new to sessions, and think I get the basics of them, they seem to act like containers holding information which you can use on at a later stage and are linked to your UID.

I am wondering how I would save the ID of a page (example ID123) on the click of a button, and what exact code I'd have in the header.

Much appreciated in advance!

EDIT:

This is on wordpress, sorry to add this, each page has an 'event ID' I want this to be stored for use later (at a kind of checkout page) sorry for not adding this!

Comment: `$_SESSION['page_id'] = $_GET['id']` Not happy with this? Explain more!

Comment: and where this page id is coming from ?

Comment: Please when you do something like this then: $_SESSION['page_id'] = intval($_GET['id'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wordpress you cannot pass custom url parameters. So you cannot send something like 
http://yourwordpresswebsite.com/?custom_param='value'

WOrdpress doesnt allow it. SO if all you want is a Post ID or a Page ID. It is easy to grab in wordpress. Do:

```
$val= $post->ID
```

Thats it and $val is set. The way I do if I have to send any custom parameters to a different file is by sending it as a form variable. There might be better ways but I am new to Wordpress and php too. So this is what I do:

```
<?php
echo "<form action='php_file.php' method='post' name='form_name'>
<input type='hidden' name='eventid' value='$event_id' />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>";

?>
```

If you want this to be your session info you can just add it in your php file where you are collecting the above fields.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['pageId'] = (int) $_GET['eventid'];

/*  Do not forget to check if the get variable is clean before you perform any operations, use mysql_real_escape_string(). It is a very important security measure. */
```

This might not be the best approach as I told you I am new to wordpress too.

Comment: This basically worked. Tho it opened a few more new questions :D

Answer (score 3):

> Saving page ID within $_SESSION

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['pageId'] = (int) $_GET['ID'];
```

Now you can use `$_SESSION['pageId']` to get its value where you need.

Make sure to put `session_start();` at top of your script where you use session-related functions or `$_SESSION` array.

To unset it when you don't need it anymore, you would do:

```
unset($_SESSION['pageId']);
session_destroy();
session_regenerate_id();
```

---

## update

On button click you would do something like this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btnId');
btn.onClick = function() {
  window.location = 'saveSession.php?id=xxx' // replace xxx with your id value
};
```

Now in `saveSession.php` you wll have to use code like shown above for storing it in session.

You can also use Ajax though.

Comment: how we will determine that `$_GET['id']` is actually page id ?

Comment: Then rename it and use another name like "pid" or "pageid"

Comment: So this will only be 'stored' once I click the 'add' button?

Comment: i mean page if page url contain id then i am getting sense here, but in question there is no reference to how he is sending page id

Comment: I have a tag that can print out the page ID, and I only want the ID saved in the session when the users clicks a button. If this is still confusing I can re-write the original post!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and give it a spin and get back on here after :)